# .htaccess override IndexIgnore *, IndexIgnore nothing

Tags: .htaccess, overriding

I have a directory with an .htaccess file having the setting `IndexIgnore *`. How can I set a subdirectory to not ignore anything, or to ignore the negation of everything, so as to override the parent directory's IndexIgnore? Like `IndexIgnore ^*`, only a working version thereof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible because [IndexIgnore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) list is always appended in the existing list (from parent .htaccess). There is now way to overwrite this directive AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `IndexIgnoreReset ON` before the new IndexIgnore directive.
And then, to show everything in the sub folder use `IndexIgnore "."`
Check the documentation at:
[IndexIgnoreReset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignorereset)

Answer (score 0):

In `<Directory>` block you can add:

```
IndexIgnoreReset ON
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
```

This will override config for this specific `<Directory>`

Comment: Same applies  for other blocks.